# Get range in ordered collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have an ordered collection of `DateTime` values. I want to retrieve all the values in the collection between a particular start and end time. What collection should I use to do this in the most efficient way and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `List<T>` but keep it ordered. Use the [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) method to find your start `DateTime` within the list. Note that it returns:

> The zero-based index of item in the sorted List, if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.

So if the value is negative you will need to apply a bitwise complement (`~` operator) to find the first index that is within range. You can then use the same process and subtract 1 to find the last element within range.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ (as this is one of your tags), you can do it like this:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> orderedDateTimes; // Your ordered DateTime collection
DateTime start;     // The start date/time, inclusive
DateTime end;       // The end date/time, inclusive

var range = orderedDateTimes
            .SkipWhile(dt => dt < start)
            .TakeWhile(dt => dt <= end);
```

This will take *O(n)* worst case to get a range. However, you can force the result into a list or array to be able to reuse it efficiently:

```
DateTime[] rangeArray = range.ToArray();
// -or-
List<DateTime> rangeList = range.ToList();
```

Comment: It would not take any advantage of fact, that collection is already sorted. I don't think LINQ is a good choice for that problem.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: If the collection was not sorted, my code would not work. So it _does_ take advantage of that. However, not to the fullest extend possible (binary search and such). But he added the LINQ tag, so I replied.